# How do I run a command on multiple files

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, wildcards, recursive

This is pretty basic, I have a folder with several subfolders of JS files and i want to run Google's Clojure compiler on all of the files in those folders. The command to process a single file is as follows:

```
java -jar compiler.jar --js filename.js --js_output_file newfilename.js
```

How do I modify this to run on every JS file in my directory structure?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use `find`:

```
find . -name "*.js" -exec java -jar compiler.jar --js {} --js_output_file new{} \;
```

Comment: Thanks, and i can probably leverage this to rename everything because the original JS files needs to be overwritten

Comment: In case the --js and --js_output_file need to differ I would make a two-line script that takes the filename as a parameter, write output to temporary file and `mv` the file to the original name.

Comment: If you want to avoid creating a separate script `find -name '*.js' | while read jsfile; do java -jar compiler.jar --js "$jsfile" --js_output_file "new$jsfile" && mv "new$jsfile" "$jsfile"; done` should do the trick.

Comment: `find -exec` is great for simple commands. for complex ones `find | xargs` is much better and also it allows to run commands in parallel.

Comment: @rush maybe explain why `xargs` is better?

Comment: @MelBoyce, the main advantage is that `xargs` can easily run commands in parallel and control maximum number of simultaneous processes (`-P` option).

Answer (score 16):

You can also use a simple `for` loop, especially if the files are within a single directory (no subdirectories). It can be modified to work with subdirectories as well.

Without recursion:

```bash
for filename in ./*.js
do
    java -jar compiler.jar --js "${filename}" --js_output_file "new${filename}"
done
```

or as an equivalent one-liner:

```bash
for filename in ./*.js; do java -jar compiler.jar --js "${filename}" --js_output_file "new${filename}"; done
```

To recurse into subdirectories (requires GNU bash 4.0 or newer) (thanks [@ChrisDown](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/10762/chris-down)):

```bash
shopt -s globstar
for filename in ./**/*.js; do
    java -jar compiler.jar --js "${filename}" --js_output_file "new${filename}"
done
```

Comment: This does not recurse subdirectories as asked in the question. With bash4+, you can use `globstar` to do so.

Comment: Yep, it's a good answer and great to know, but the other answer does exactly what i need it to.

Comment: Ohh, I managed to completely miss the "several subfolders" part. Sorry. Leaving the answer around for completeness' sake, though.

Comment: @ChrisDown Would you be so kind as to edit an example of globstar into the answer?

Comment: @ChrisDown as far as I know, there is no way to use globstar for certain extension match. Only `**` to match the whole tree.

Comment: @rush Since `**` can match an arbitrary level of recursion, `**/*.js` works: http://sprunge.us/PXQK

Comment: It's generally a good idea to use `for f in ./*.js; do` or `for f in ./**/*.js; do` in order to protect yourself from filenames beginning with a `-` (I don't know if that's necessary in this case, but it's a good habit anyway).

Comment: @evilsoup In general, that's a good idea. In this particular case, we are talking about explicit command line arguments to specify the file name, so file names beginning with hyphens should not be an issue. Still, I'm adding it to the answer.